# How do you add constant space between centered items in CSS? (EDIT)

Tags: html, css, containers, word-wrap, centering

I want to create a website, part of which has two elements in a container: title text and a button. I want to place them in the center of the main axis (the container), with some space between them. I don't like the `justify-content: space-around` option because it leaves too much space in the middle. So to do this, I would use left/right margins for each of the elements. But I also want to use `flex-wrap: wrap;`, meaning that if the screen size is too small to fit both of the elements, css would transfer the button to the next line. Every time this happens however, the `margin-left` still remains on the button, so it looks off-centered (see [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fvc6A.png)).

Any ideas? Thanks.

**EDIT: Using media queries messes things up, so my new question is this: Is there a way to make the space between two centered elements hold constant to all screen sizes without margins?**

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Answer (score 0):

You can set the margin only for bigger screen sizes using CSS media queries

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for [`justify-content: space-evenly`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content) in combination with [`text-align: center`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-align), [`align-items: center`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/align-items), and [`flex-wrap: wrap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-wrap). This will separate the content out evenly, whilst simultaneously allowing it to wrap around without any margins when the viewport isn't wide enough to contain both elements.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  text-align: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 100px;
  /*max-width: 80px;*/ /* Turn on to see the wrap */
}

.content {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">content</div>
  <div class="content">content</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Just have to through the same old argument out (just for the people who don't know), no edge browser support

Comment: This is what I did before but is there a way to retain the space between the first and second elements when changing screen size?